# Widget not scrolling - possible due to missing widget ID?

Tags: wordpress, widget

I am trying to make a scrolling button in wordpress. I can get a search function widget to scroll, but not a button widget. The following code appears to be the problem:

```
   <aside class="sidebar sidebar-primary widget-area" role="complementary" aria-label="Primary Sidebar" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPSideBar">
<!-- fixed widget --><a href="www.weather.com" class="medium otw-red square otw-button">Leave This Site Now!</a>
<!-- fixed widget --><section id="search-2" class="widget widget_search">
<div class="widget-wrap"><form class="search-form" itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SearchAction" method="get" action="http://www.example.org/" role="search">
<meta itemprop="target" content="http://www.example.org/?s={s}"/><input itemprop="query-input" type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search this website &#x2026;" />
<input type="submit" value="Search"  /></form></div></section>
```

Plugins used: 
     Button plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/buttons-shortcode-and-widget/

Q2W3 button plugin (I can only post one link because I am a new user)

I am relatively new to this, but it appears that the problem is that shortcode widgets have no widget ID. How would I create an id for a shortcode widget, and where would I place the code?

Comment: I suggest you research a little more show us what you trying, etc.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the solution [here](https://amethystwebsitedesign.com/how-to-use-shortcodes-in-your-wordpress-website-sidebar/). All I had to do was create a text widget, insert it in the sidebar, and place the shortcode there.